# div's go block first, and then inline

Tags: html, position, block, inline

I have a bunch of div's inside a parent div. I want the child div's to go one on top of another (block), but when they exceed the height of the parent div, I want them to go to the right (inline). I attached an image and my code showing the problem.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="howhigh">
<div class="part">hi</div>
<div class="part">hi</div>
<div class="part">hi</div>
<div class="part">hi</div>
<div class="part">hi</div>
<div class="part">hi</div>
<div class="part">hi</div>
<div class="part">hi</div>
<div class="part">hi</div>
<div class="part">hi</div>
<div class="part">hi</div>
<div class="part">hi</div>
<div class="part">hi</div>
<div class="part">hi</div>
<div class="part">hi</div>
<div class="part">hi</div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#howhigh {
    width: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;


}

.part {
    width: 10%;
    display: block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS3 Multiple column layout](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) but this will cut your div in half at the end of a column if it needs to.
**[Columnflow](http://labs.ft.com/articles/ft-columnflow/)** from FTlabs is an advanced implementation of these CSS features as a script, Undefined support of IE though, it may not be a polyfill.

Otherwise you'll have to create columns by wrapping a bunch of div in a container